# Add n numbers which are in a list and return the total

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I an trying to define a function that will add `n` numbers which are in a list and return the total. My code:

```
def addition():
    i = True
    while i:
        print("You chose addition")
        print()
        addition_values_list = []
        addition_count = int(input("Enter number of count: "))
        for i in range(1,addition_count+1):
            values = int(input(f"Enter value of number {i}:  "))
            addition_values_list.append(values)
        for j in range(1,len(addition_values_list+1)):  # <-- The error occurs here.
            total = total + (addition_values_list[j])  # <--
        print(total)
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you post the error it is giving you?

Comment: for j in range(1,len(addition_values_list+1)):
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: `len(addition_values_list+1)`: You are adding 1 to `list` not `len`

Comment: also in addition `total` is not defined either and will throw an error when you try to use it before its assigned

Answer (score 4):

1. `addition_values_list` is a list. You can't add integer (`1`) to a list.
2. You run from 1 to `len(addition_values_list)`. In Python, indexes start from 0.
3. You have to reset `total` to some value before using `total + ...`

So the code should look like:

```
total = 0
for j in range(len(addition_values_list)):
    total = total + (addition_values_list[j])
```

Please note that you can use the `for` loop to get the value instantly. You don't have to use indexes here:

```
total = 0
for j in addition_values_list:
    total = total + j
```

And you can just use `sum()` which will probably be faster:

```
sum(addition_values_list)
```

Comment: thanks for `sum(addition_values_list)` didnt know that